# Godel theorem: confusion on "PM is consistent -> PM's consistency is not PM-provable"

Tags: incompleteness

I came to a good summary of Godel's incompleteness theorem proof (http://www.jamieyorkpress.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/G%C3%B6dels-proof-summary.pdf) but I'm confused on one step which leads to the conclusion that "PM is consistent -> PM's consistency is not PM-provable." Would appreciate someone can enlighten me. Because I haven't finished reading the original paper, I based my understanding on this summary. I could be confused because of this summary is wrong.

As the summary says, assuming PM is consistent, then the formula G "G is not PM-provable" is not PM-provable. Then meta-mathematically, it's clear that G is true, therefore PM is incomplete.

This conclusion: "PM is consistent -> PM is incomplete" (*) is then used as a theorem in a series of steps that leads to a contradiction which proves that "PM is consistent -> PM's consistency is not PM-provable". Basically:

```
"PM is consistent and such consistency is PM-provable" ->   
     (using (*) here.  This is the step I'm confused about)
"PM's incompleteness is PM-provable" ->
"G is PM-provable" -> contradiction.
```

My confusion is that (* ) is clearly the conclusion of a meta-mathematical proof. Can we use that as part of a PM-proof? Because the above proof uses (*), I wonder we therefore can't say G is PM-provable but just G is meta-mathematically-provable, which doesn't lead to any contradiction with the conclusion that "G is not PM-provable"?

Hope I've explained my confusion clearly. Would appreciate any kind of replies. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a very good question! Many treatments of Goedel's theorem gloss over exactly *where* the relevant statements are being proved.

Here's what's going on:

- Goedel's argument, though on the face of it a metamathematical one, can be formulated in a sufficiently powerful theory. PA, for instance, is more than powerful enough for the task! That is, the theory PA *itself* proves, "If PA is consistent, then PA is incomplete."

Actually, this is *not quite* due to Goedel, but rather [Rosser's improvement of Goedel's argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosser's_trick); Goedel original showed a somewhat weaker fact.

- Now, PA can go on to prove, via the usual argument, the statement: "If PA is consistent, then PA does not prove its own consistency."

However, note the constant hypothesis "If PA is consistent." The unqualified claim $$\mbox{PA is incomplete}$$ is **not** provable in PA alone; rather a stronger theory, capable of proving PA's consistency, is needed. Metamathematically, this corresponds to our *accepting that PA is consistent*. (Goedel's original argument had even more metamathematical baggage: it required that we *accept that PA is **true***, or at least [correct about a certain class of propositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A9-consistent_theory). Rosser's improvement was to reduce the assumption needed to exactly "PA is consistent.")

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I see that you mean the conclusion "PA is consistent -> PA is incomplete" is provable within PA. I don't quite understand PA. Let me try to understand PA first. Thanks!

Comment: @ioslearner You can replace "PA" with "PM" if you prefer; the result holds for any reasonable theory able to prove basic facts about arithmetic.